# Implementing Comparable

Tags: java

```
    import java.util.*;  
    class A implements Comparable<A>  
    {  
        int a;  
        public int compareTo(A other)  
        {  
            A a1 = (A) other; //No need of cast  
            if(this.a == other.a ) return 0;  
            if(this.a < other.a )  return -1;  
            return 1;  
        }  
    }  
    class ctest  
    {  
        public static void main(String args[])  
        {    
            String[] names = {"OOP","BITS","PILANI"};  
            Arrays.sort(names);  
            int[] data = { 10,-45,87,0,20,21 };  
            Arrays.sort(data);    

            A[] arr = new A[5];  
            arr[0] = new A();  
            arr[1] = new A();  
            arr[2] = new A();  
            arr[3] = new A();   
            arr[4] = new A();  
            Arrays.sort(arr);  
        }  
    }
```

This gives the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable  
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)  
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)  
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)  
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Here my code. You fix. Eh?

Comment: I have just run your code without getting any exceptions... Do you by any chance have more than one `A` class and you import the wrong one?

Comment: You don't even show line numbers.

Comment: we don't need no stinking line numbers!

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys no. But we do need code that actually fails.

Comment: I assume the `A a1 = (A) other; //No need of cast ` comment is by your lecturer?

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys I think the idea was to ask the OP to show the line on which the exception is thrown.

Comment: Yeah but you can tell that from the stacktrace - at `java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)` - anyway the code as written does not produce the error.

Comment: Since when is `int[] data = { 10,-45,87,0,20,21 }; ` a valid Java code? I thought it had to be `int[] data = int[]{ 10,-45,87,0,20,21 }; `.

Comment: @JanDvorak - that's perfectly valid

Comment: i'm still gettin error in, i'm using jdk 7, please help

Comment: @Brometheus edit and post the full .java file with whatever file name you are using

Comment: @Brometheus Wild guess: what happens if you add `@Override` before the `compareTo` method?

Comment: @assylias works fine now, maybe some wrong class was being imported, I changed the project. Sorry for a silly question, I'm a  beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

This means the version of `A` you are running is not Comparable. Most likely you have two versions of A or you didn't build the class correctly.  I suggest using an IDE to build you classes and doing a clean build should fix this.

BTW: All your A are the same, so sorting them won't do anything. You can fix these once you have fixed the build.